# How would 2_sum be solved faster than O(n^2) time in Python?

Tags: python

```
s = [1,2]
target = 4


#1,6,5,-2,11

two_sum = []
sum_up = 0
for a in s:
    sum_up = sum_up + a
    # when target-a is in s
    # Do not look in S. But
    # instead check that a
    # is not in two_sum.
    if a not in two_sum:
        # Append is O(1)
        two_sum.append(target-a)
        



if target < sum_up:
    # since we checked that a
    # is not in two_sum.
    # Two_sum should be < len(s)
    # if and only if it has
    # a solution
    if len(two_sum) < len(s):
        print('yes')
```

My goal is to solve 2_sum faster than quadratic time. I think I achieved that goal, but I'm not sure if my code works on all cases. Perhaps someone can explain to me how you would solve 2_sum in O(N) time.

### Question

Does my code solve 2_sum and is it faster than O(N^2) time?

What better ways could I write this code? (eg. variable names and functions)

Comment: Is your goal just to determine *if* there are two elements that sum to the target, or to identify *which* elements sum to target?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Just determine. By the way, I just recently found a bug. when S has only two elements it won't return any answer to the decision problem. (eg. [2,2] target = 4)

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
if a not in two_sum:
```

you search through this list, which requires O(n) time in the worst case. You do that for every iteration through `n` making this quadratic — it's essentially a nested loop. If you can make the determination if you've seen the `target - a` in constant time, you could make this linear. You can do that with a set because testing if a set contains a value is a constant time operation. This might look something like:

```
l = [1, 5, 4, 2]

def two_sum(l, target):
    seen = set()
    for n in l:
        if target - n in seen: # constant time test
            return True        # since you just need a Boolean you can bail early
        seen.add(n) 
    return False

print(two_sum(l, 10))
# False

print(two_sum(l, 7))
# True

print(two_sum(l, 6))
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, please check this one for space complexity...

```
def two_sum(a, t):
    i = 0
    j = len(a) - 1
    while i < len(a):
        s = a[i] + a[j]
        if s == t:
            #print(a[i], a[j])
            return True
        elif s > t:
            j -= 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return False
```

This one doesn't need any container for two sum pair as keep the time complexity of using set. However, the performance could be kind of lower than using set.